# Dividing students into classrooms - how many different scenarios?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm struggling to figure out a solution to a real world problem I've encountered in work that I'm sure mathematics has already solved for me. I don't have any math education (beyond high school, apologies) and have spent a long time searching for an answer to this, with no success. I guess that this is a permutations or combinations problem, but I really don't know.

A "simple" analogy of my problem is as follows:

I have 3 students (John, Paul and George) and want to put them into classrooms. There are no other students. There are no restrictions on how many classrooms there are.

My question is: How many different scenarios can there be (and how many classrooms are used in each scenario)? For example, in this scenario:

- at a minimum there must 1 classroom with all three students
- at a maximum there could 3 class rooms with 1 student in each
- there could also be scenarios where there are 2 class rooms, with John and Paul in the first room and George in the second, or John and George in the first room wil Paul in the second, etc.

It's not important what order people are within an individual classroom, but it's important who is in the class. The order of the classes is also not important. I just need to know how many scenarios there could be.

I have included a table below which shows that there could be 5 different scenarios for this example (I think!!), ranging from using 1 classroom (with everyone in it) to using 3 separate rooms, with 1 student in each.

My problem is how could I do this calculation for any number of students....potentially up to 100!

Ultimately I'll be trying to use Excel or Alteryx or something like that to try and generate all the different scenarios.....but that's a problem for another day!

| Scenario | Classroom | Classroom | Classroom | Num Classrooms Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John, Paul George |  |  | 1 |
| 2 | John, Paul | George |  | 2 |
| 3 | John, George | Paul |  | 2 |
| 4 | Paul, George | John |  | 2 |
| 5 | John | Paul | George | 3 |

Thank you for any help or advice you can give. It will be very much appreciated.

Colm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @TravorLZH provided a perfectly reasonable explanation of how to calculate these numbers, the discussion was about the real world application to students, so I wanted to add a notable addendum.

This distribution of numbers is known as the Bell numbers, and while they are reasonable for small inputs, they grow incredibly quickly.  Consider the following values:

3 students $\rightarrow$ 5 outcomes 
5 students $\rightarrow$ 52 outcomes 
7 students $\rightarrow$ 877 outcomes 
10 students $\rightarrow$ 115,975 outcomes

As such, the original post postulated possibly needing outcomes "potentially up to 100 students".  I submit that the hypothetical building with unlimited classrooms in theory is nice, but that any building the poster actually has access to does not in fact have the 51,724,158,235,372 rooms it would take for 20 students, much less 100 students.

---

**Edit**: To see how 5 students gives 52 outcomes, consider:
One room:
{5}  - 1 outcome
{ABCDE}
Two rooms:
{4,1} - 5 outcomes (5 diff students can be alone in the second room)
{ABCD,E},{ABCE,D},{ABDE,C},{ACDE,B},{BCDE,A}
{3,2} - 10 outcomes (5 first students * 4 second students / 2 for order)
{ABC,DE},{ABD,CE},{ABE,CD},{ACD,BE},{ACE,BD},
{ADE,BC},{BCD,AE},{BCE,AD},{BDE,AC},{CDE,AB}
Three rooms:
{3,1,1} - 10 outcomes (split up the kids from previous example)
{ABC,D,E},{ABD,C,E},{ABE,C,D},{ACD,B,E},{ACE,B,D},
{ADE,B,C},{BCD,A,E},{BCE,A,D},{BDE,A,C},{CDE,A,B}
{2,2,1} - 15 outcomes (5 choices for last room, 3 choices to mix others)
{AB,CD,E},{AC,BD,E},{AD,BC,E},{AB,CE,D},{AC,BE,D}
{AE,BC,D},{AB,DE,C},{AD,BE,C},{AE,BD,C},{AC,DE,B}
{AD,CE,B},{AE,CD,B},{BC,DE,A},{BD,CE,A},{BE,CD,A}
Four rooms:
{2,1,1,1} - 10 outcomes (5*4/2 ways to have a pair)
{AB,C,D,E},{AC,B,D,E},{AD,B,C,E},{AE,B,C,D},{BC,A,D,E}
{BD,A,C,E},{BE,A,C,D},{CD,A,B,E},{CE,A,B,D},{DE,A,B,C}
Five rooms:
{1,1,1,1,1} - 1 outcome

Altogether, that's 52 outcomes.

A fast way to do these calculations for small numbers of students is called the Bell triangle, which starts with a 1 in the first two positions, and the value of each new spot is the sum of the spot to the left and the upper left, starting new rows with the end of the previous row, such that:

```
    1
    1   2
    2   3   5
    5   7  10  15
   15  20  27  37   52
   52  67  87 114  151  203
```

Thus there are 52 outcomes for 5 students, 203 outcomes for 6 students, and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is also really helpful. Agreed, it would be great to be in a position to an unlimited number of classrooms, my real world example isn't THAT real world. While I did mention in my original post potentially up to 100 students, in the vast majority of cases, I suspect the number of "students" will be < 10. I'm struggling, however, to work through the interpretation of some of the notation in @TravorLZH's answer (it's a long time since I studied math!). Would it be possible for you to run through the calculations for the first couple of outcomes where there are 5 students?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. It has been very useful to me in reaching a (sort of) solution to my real world issue.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, we are finding the number of ways to partition $n$ students into $k$ different groups. Let $a_{n,k}$ denote this number. Then it is certain that $a_{n,1}=1$ and $a_{n,k}=0$ whenever $n<k$. As a result, we might find certain recursive relations helpful in deriving a closed form for this quantity.

If we were to assign one student to the first classroom. Then there will be $n$ ways for us to pick the first student and $a_{n-1,k-1}$ ways for us to assign the remaining students to the remaining $k-1$ classrooms. Similarly, there will be $\binom nm$ ways to assign $m$ students to the first classroom and $a_{n-m,k-1}$ to assign remaining students to other classrooms. Since we can choose at most $n$ students, we obtain the following recursive relation:

$$
a_{n,k}=\sum_{1\le m\le n}\binom nma_{n-m,k-1}
$$

Because OP mentions that each classroom is considered the same, we will have to divide $a_{n,k}$ by $k!$ to obtain the desired number of scenarios:

For example let $k=2$, it follows from binomial theorem that

$$
a_{n,2}=\sum_{1\le m\le n}\binom nma_{n-m,1}=\sum_{0\le m\le n}\binom nm-2=2^n-2
$$

Then the number of ways to assign 3 students into 2 classrooms is exactly $a_{3,2}/2!=(2^3-2)/2=3$.

For the case when $k=n$, we can use the iteration formula to get

\begin{aligned}
a_{n,n}
&=\sum_{1\le m\le n}\binom nma_{n-m,n-1}=\binom n1a_{n-1,n-1} \\
&=na_{n-1,n-1}=n(n-1)a_{n-2,n-2} \\
&=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot a_{1,1}=n!
\end{aligned}

Since the order of classroom is not taken into consideration, there are exactly $a_{n,n}/n!=1$ way to assign $n$ students into $n$ classrooms. This is also consistent with OP's spreadsheet.

Putting everything together, we obtain the following result:

Let $a_{n,k}/k!$ denote the number of ways to assign $n$ students into $k$ classrooms according to OP's specifications. Then $a_{n,1}=1$ and

$$
a_{n,k}=\sum_{1\le m\le n}\binom nma_{n-m,k-1}
$$

Moreover, $a_{n,k}=0$ whenever $n>k$. Hopefully this can address your concern!

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort you put in to providing your detailed and helpful answer. I've been working through it for the last couple of hours but am having trouble making the math work.

I wonder would it be possible for you to run through one example of how your formula works; say in a scenario where I know that the number of students $n is going to be 5.....could you work through your example that shows how to get to the number of possible scenarios and to determine what k (the number of rooms occupied) is for each scenario? 

Thank you again in advance.